# Android ask for next input only if the prior input is yes

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing a Data Request Form via native android, where the user is supposed to enter various fields. Consider below scenario :

1. One of the fields asks `Insurance?`, and it seeks `Yes/No` input.
2. If the input of the prior field was `Yes`, only then it should ask for `Insurance Number` .

| Label | Input |
| --- | --- |
| Insurance? *(TextView)* | * Yes * No *(RadioGroup)* |

If the prior input is `Yes`, only then we should get a next request like:

| Label | Input |
| --- | --- |
| Insurance Number *(TextView)* | ......................... *(EditView)* |

Can someone please help me understand how can I implement this?
Tried searching for this query but couldn't find. If this question is duplicate, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, when the user selects "Yes" in the "Insurance?" field, the "Insurance Number" field becomes visible, and when they select "No," it becomes hidden.[res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gBvr.png)

```
     RadioGroup radioGroupInsurance =findViewById(R.id.radioGroupInsurance);
      TextView textViewInsuranceNumber = findViewById(R.id.textViewInsuranceNumber);
     EditText editTextInsuranceNumber =findViewById(R.id.editTextInsuranceNumber);

    radioGroupInsurance.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.radioYes) {
            textViewInsuranceNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editTextInsuranceNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioNo) {
            textViewInsuranceNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editTextInsuranceNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a radio group for YES and NO then you can do like below to get the selected index

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

You should have your insurance number Label and Text View in visibility gone or invisible state.

Based on the radio button selected index, programatically change the visbility to visible or invisible.